# adding an image to .dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Im writing a DLL that is supposed to store resources for my program. How can i add a simple .bmp image to a .dll in Visual Studio 2010? I I've been searching for a while but couldn't find any useful documentation. Thank you.

Comment: It is fairly hard to miss, do always mention that you're using the Express edition in your questions.  Stuff is missing in that edition, the resource editor for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a resource script.  [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxdy04be%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) provides step-by-step instructions for creating a resource script, as well as adding resources like bitmaps and strings.

Answer (score 1):

Add it as a `resource` to your assembly.