# Is it possible to compile/include an image into a DLL in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a DLL that I created, that contains an image file on my computer and when I go to use that DLL on client's computer it complains that it can't find it. Instead of moving the image to the programs directory where I'm using the DLL, is it possible to compile the image right into the DLL?

Is that even possible ?

OR

Do I always have to keep an image in some local directory that I package up with the program?

Comment: `const char img[] = { .... };`

Comment: Depends what you want to do with this image. But why doing complicated DLL things when there is the easy directory solution?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649808/adding-an-image-to-dll.